# Solution to configure a NAS's FTP through blocked ports

Tags: ftp, port-forwarding, network-attached-storage, port

Here's my problem in a nutshell:

1) My ISP blocks FTP ports on their side (not on the router, so I can't control that)
2) My Buffalo NAS won't let me change the default FTP ports
3) My ISP's modem/router won't let me set the outside and inside ports separately for port forwarding.  ex., I can forward port 666 to an internal IP address only on port 666...not port 666 (WAN) to port 20 (LAN)

This basically means that both the ISP and the Buffalo NAS make it so I can't use FTP.  I've thought about perhaps mapping the NAS's shares to network drives on one computer and having THAT computer run an FTP server.  I've heard there are network issues with doing it that way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping a drive to the NAS from another machine that's capable of running an FTP server on alternative ports should be fine.  From a throughput perspective, server to NAS traffic is not going to be the bottleneck here.

Comment: I have it to the point where I can view the files over the LAN through FTP; now it's just a matter of connecting to the server over the internet...which doesn't seem to be working.  I'm already running a connection similar to what Antonius has suggested - and I've set DMZ on both the modem and the router as well as set up port forwarding on both...nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another router behind the ISP's router.  My suggestion would be an ASUS WL-520GU:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320023

with TomatoUSB installed:

http://tomatousb.org/

Then you set things up like so:

```
  208.80.x.x:666   <-- your external ip
       |
  ISP Modem
       |
  192.168.1.x:666  <-- internal ip from ISP modem
       |
  Your Router running nat
       |
  192.168.2.x:21  <-- internal ip on a seperate network
```

Comment: I'm actually already running my network like this.  I'm not able to connect via the internet though...I'm using Telus...I don't know if they're blocking something.